# <div> shrinks when float is applied to its sub elements

Tags: html, css, css-float

I am trying to make an element container within the main container of my website. To make the element container in a line, I applied `float:left;` to them. But when I added `float` to them,the main container shrinks! I tried applying `clear:both` to the main container, but nothing changes.

CSS :

```
#main_container
{
    clear:both;
    margin-top:20px;
    padding:20px 10px 30px 15px;
    background:#ccc;
}
.element_container
{
    float:left;
    width:238px;
    height:300px;
    border:1px solid #000;
}
```

HTML :

```
<div id="main_container">

    <div class="element_container"></div>

    <div class="element_container"></div>

    <div class="element_container"></div>

</div>
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for asking this question! It helped me tremendously!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try adding:

```
overflow: auto;
```

to `#main_container`

**EDIT:** As an alternative float clearing method you can use :after, as explained [here](http://robertnyman.com/2007/04/12/how-to-clear-css-floats-without-extra-markup-different-techniques-explained/).

Comment: Cool - there are other ways to clear floats too. overflow: auto; is my preference. But you can also use :after which is explained here: http://robertnyman.com/2007/04/12/how-to-clear-css-floats-without-extra-markup-different-techniques-explained/

Comment: This was extremely helpful. Thanks for the answer! I had been racking my brain on this for a few weeks, and had a really crappy fix in place; which didn't scale well.

Answer (score 1):

Add `overflow: hidden;` to main container -

```
#main_container
{
    clear:both;
    margin-top:20px;
    padding:20px 10px 30px 15px;
    background:#ccc;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try giving the width of the div to 100%.
Maybe this will help.

Answer (score 0):

Hi now two option of this solution now do this

first is

```
<div id="main_container">

    <div class="element_container"></div>

    <div class="element_container"></div>

    <div class="element_container"></div>
  <div class="" style="clear:both;"></div> //  add this in your html 
</div>
```

now second is define your main Container `Overflow`

```
#main_container{
overflow:hidden;
}
```