# HTML/CSS: Make a wrapper extend to fit the height of its children

Tags: html, css

I am making a website. All the content is stored in a wrapper DIV. The content DIV has a border style assigned to it.

I want the height of the wrapper DIV to be tall enough to fit it's content, so the border goes to the end of the page.

I thought this would happen by default, as [height:auto](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_height.asp) is the default value of all elements.

Here is my [page](http://olo.uk.com/testx/).

Thanks for any help that can be offered.

Comment: What if a content-elements has `position:fixed`? Should they be warpped too?

Comment: do you mean this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10155344/auto-height-div-with-overflow-and-scroll-when-needed   ?

Comment: @PeterRader. No the position:fixed shouldn't be wrapped. Joum: No, I just want my wrapper to expand in height to fill its children.

Comment: And what if a content-div has fixed size and  `overflow:visible` or `hidden` and its contents is oversized?

Comment: @PeterRader I just want the wrapper DIV's height to be as big as its contents. If the content-divs have overflow:hidden, then the excess content will be hidden, so it won't affect the height of the wrapper DIV. If the content-div has overflow:visible, then the wrapper DIV should expand in height to fit that content.

Comment: In respecting of `overflow:visible` it will may take **massive calculation** depending on complexity of the DOM. Are you sure[y/N]?

Comment: @PeterRader I just want the wrapper DIV to expand to its contents. I thought that is the normal behaviour of a DIV and was not expecting it to be so complex!

Comment: @big_smile in case of element-oversizes that are wrapped in elements using `overflow:visible` its complex.

Answer (score 2):

Just make wrapper div style

```
overflow: auto
```

Comment: Flow: auto doesn't do anything. Do you mean overflow:auto - That adds scroll bars. (Overflow:visible doesn't do anything, and overflow:hidden hides the content).

Comment: yes, i meant overflow. changed it. it should really expand to the contents of its children

Comment: This works, you only need to change both these values: `#wrapper { overflow: auto or hidden; height: auto;}` . More info here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11498946/div-shrinks-when-float-is-applied-to-its-sub-elements

Comment: @staono: I have used before/after to add a background behind the wrapper. If I use overflow, the before/after elements are hidden. How can I keep them visible.

Answer (score 1):

```
html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  /* not height: 100%; otherwise you're 
   * fixing it to the height of the viewport 
   */
  min-height: 100%; 
}

.wrapper {
  /* some kind of clearfix is 
   * necessary because your content 
   * is floated
   */
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: I tried this but it just hides the content that is outside of the wrapper.

Comment: you need to take 'height: 100%' OFF of the body. Make sure it is 'min-height' not 'height'. forcing a height means the body will never be the same height as the content within it which is why your overflow is hiding the content.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly you want to create a full height web site?

If so, try [sticky footer](http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/).

Comment: I just want the wrapper height to expand to fit it's children.

Answer (score 0):

Just use a div to nest contents and "do not" give it any height. By default, it will fit it's children. If necessary, you may give a `display: block`.

Here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/8bP9b/

Comment: my advise: consider redesigning your page layout. It will make it "stable" and "better".

Comment: @blasteralfred Ψ: Could you expand on your comments.